# A question about minimal polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $E/F$ a field extension and $f=X^n-a \in F[X]$  irreducible polynomial and and $m \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $m|n$ and $\rho$ a root of $f$.

Prove that the minimal polynomial of $\rho^m$ is $g=X^{n/m}-a$

One thought is to prove that $g$ is irreducible over $F$.If $g$ was not irreducible then we know that $irr(\rho^m,F)|g$

Can someone help me to reach a contradiction or give me a hint to solve it straight forward without contradiction?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Eric Wofsey's answer is better. But another track is the following: let $E'=F(\rho)$ and  let $L=F(\rho^m)$. Let $d=n/m$. Then think about why $[E':L] \leq m$ (consider $X^m-\rho^m$) and $[L:F] \leq d$. Then since $n=[E':F]=[E':L][L:F]\leq md =n$ the inequalities have to be equalities, in particular $[L:F]=d$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:  Note that $f(X)=g(X^m)$.  Suppose you could factor $g(X)=p(X)q(X)$.  What would this tell you about $f(X)$?

Comment: that f is not irreducible